# Mongoose geospatial intersect with polygon

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've been searching for an hour or so and can't seem to find a solution to this.

I have a defined polygon in my Node.js application stored as:

`[[-0.4449,51.4532],[-0.4586,51.4562],[-0.4591,51.4572],...`

Where each point is given as `[lng,lat]`.

In my MongoDB collection I have objects with the following structure:

```
_id: ...
givenID: ...
location: [lng, lat]
...
```

And I'm representing the `location` property as:

```
  location: {
    type: [Number]
  },
```

in my `mongoose` schema.

I can query all records out and the `schema` maps the `location` correctly and I get `[lng, lat]` back as expected, but I can't seem to execute an `intersects` on any of my documents in my collection.

My query is as following:

```
  let geoJson ={
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": geozone
  };

  try {
    const test = await GpsLog.where('location').intersects().geometry({
      type: "Polygon",
      coordinates: geozone
    });
```

where `geozone` is the polygon listed above.

I have a `2dsphere` index on the `location` in each document too for reference.

If I pass in the `geospatial type` as a `LineString` I get back 0 records, but passing it in as a `Polygon` gives me `geojson coordinates must be an array`, but as far as I can tell they are an array (obviously).

Is there something I've missed? I'm sure the bug is something tiny that I haven't spotted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly bug, the `coordinates` property needed to be wrapped in *another* set of `[ ]` for it to be a valid `Polygon`. Works fine now.